# Nonsense d3 pick syntax error

Tags: pick

I made the following queries in d3 and got the following results:

```
:list      product-master with qoh > 99 and with categ eni
[401] no items present.
:list      product-master with qoh > 9 and with categ eni
[4] syntax error
```

Why does the query with the 99 parse, while the query with the 9 generates a syntax error?

Comment: Show more code or something. This does not look like the D3 I am familiar with.

Comment: It is a pick query on a d3 multivalue database.  Stack Overflow automatically converted my d3 tag into d3.js for I am not sure what reason.  There really isn't any more code to show, there are two one line statements, one of which works and one of which doesn't, but I have no idea why one would work while the other would generate a syntax error, hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default MD has an item called '9', rather than regarding that value as a literal, it's seeing a definition after the ">", which isn't legal. If you put your literals in quotes it'll work for you.

Similarly, your reference to eni is ambiguous. Do you intend to find a category = "eni", or are you searching for any item that has a non-null category, with a display of the field called ENI? Quotes eliminate all of this ambiguity.

Please flag this as an Answer after you've verified it. Thanks.